# Suppress Data Validation Errors

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where I remove a value from a data range once it is selected in a dropdown box. I remove it because once selected I don't want it to appear in other dropdowns.

However by removing it from the range it makes the existing dropdown invalid as the data range no longer contains the selected value. I get an ugly red triangle in the top right corner.

I have searched and I have found there is no way to suppress this red triangle, so my existing method to select the data is stuck with it. Perhaps there is some other way I could achieve my goal of selecting data from a dynamic range that subsequently removes the selected value?

Comment: Would you be able to share a sample sheet, indicating what you want the desired result to be? I am struggling to understand exactly how this should work. Maybe adding some context about the human task you are trying to accomplish would help too.

Comment: Here you go Ian. Look at those ugly red triangles light up when you select stuff in the dropdown:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pq4JIuKHZ7tJUC1IcSOPWkoV-AEkw6Ndd3MOW01D_gQ/edit?usp=sharing

I select from the range in B and not the raw data in column A because I need the values in C to be unique. The values disappear from other dropdown boxes once you've selected them

Answer (score 0):

#### You would need Apps Script for this

Mainly because formulas are always going to update themselves. With scripts you can run it once and have the values stay as they are until you modify them.

It could be implemented in a variety of ways depending on how exactly you want this list to behave. Some things to consider are:

- Is the list of items to select always the same, or is it dynamic?
- Do you need the list of items to reset after input? How would it reset exactly?

There will probably be some more questions that would arise during development but these are the first things I would try to clarify.

#### `DataValidationBuilder`

This is what you would use in Apps Script to build your dynamic drop down. My approach, based on the limited info, might be:

- create an `onEdit` trigger (a script that runs every time there is an edit to the sheet)
- It would detect if a value has been selected from the data validation cells.
- It would check to make sure its a proper value.
- Then remove the drop down data validation from that cell and lock in the value
- Modify the "master" list of values for the rest of the cells.
- Finally it would have to rebuild the data validation for the rest of the cells.

Here is a simple snippet to demonstrate how a drop down is created in code:

```js
function createSimpleDropdown() {
  // Select a cell to insert the data validation into
  let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
  // Define a list of the items to choose from (this can be built from a range too)
  let list = ["cat", "dog", "mouse", "elephant"]
  let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation() // This sets up a new data validation object
    .requireValueInList(list, true) // this configures it to use the list and show a dropdown
    .build(); // this builds it
  // Finally, assign the rule to the cell
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

This demonstrates one cell, but it is possible to do a range also, though slightly more complex at the level of code, it greatly speeds up execution if you need to do more than a few.

You could also set this on a time-driven trigger depending on your specific workflow.

#### References

I appreciate you may not be familiar with Apps Script though, so here are a few links to get you started if that is the path you want to go down:

- [Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials)
- [Your First Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#your_first_script)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)
- [DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)

Comment: Hi Ian, sorry for the delay. That's quite a creative solution. Unfortunately you only get about 90 mins of onEdit time per day so if people are working on the sheet all day long the scripts will stop triggering quite early in the day. You just gave me an idea. I can just remove the data validation once it has been set, say once a day on a time driven script. 

That would probably be a good resource friendly compromise.

Comment: No problem, I'll add the time driven trigger to my answer to make it complete. I think you would be surprised at how much you have to do to run into quota limits, in any case, good luck.